# Rendering Partial Views using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, razor

I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888521/asp-net-mvc3-razor-views-and-partialviews-with-ajax-postbacks) and it solved my initial problems. But I don't want the partial view to be rendered only when the user clicks a link, I want to render partial views when the page is loaded and, possibly, show a progress indicator while the partial view is being loaded.

How to achieve that?

Thank you very much for reading this.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you want to load the page and then load the partial view via ajax you could create an `ActionMethod` that does something like:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     var model = new MyModel();

     if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
     {
          return PartialView( "_Partial", model.PartialModel );
     }
     else
     {
          return View( model );
     } 
}
```

and then in your page do something like:

```
$(function(){

    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        //show a progress modal of your choosing
        showProgressModal('loading');
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        //hide it
        hideProgressModal();
    });

    $.ajax({
          url: '/controller/create',
          dataType: 'html',
          success: function(data) {
             $('#myPartialContainer').html(data);
          }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Controller

```
public ActionResult GetModule(string partialName){
    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/"+partialName);
}
```

on the Default Page (using jquery ajax operation)

```
<div id='mod1'>Loading...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $("#mod1").load("/ControllerName/GetModule?partialName=test1");         
</script>
```

Comment: Do I need to put the file format of the `Partial View`? Like .cshtml

Answer (score 6):

You can render it in the initial page by writing `@Html.Partial(...)`.

Comment: Think @Html.Parital can't be used in Ajax, jquery.

Comment: @Shan: It's a server-side thing; it has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @SLaks, seems like he needs the partial views to display after the main view is displayed (probably to avoid long time initial processing). As far as I know @Html.Partial() that you propose is processed on server along with the main view. So it does not solve the mans problem. I was also tricked by the question initially.