# Error when rendering a Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, model, controller

working on a small website to get familiar with MS MVC framework and I have a partial view "Browse" that i render in a view "Index" using this:

```
@Html.Partial("Browse")
```

the problem here is that the partial "Browse" view requires a collection of objects as model which initialized in the "Browse" function of a Controller called "Products", so unless i make a call to the Browse method of the controller, my view will always have a null collection.

is it possible to initialize the collection before rendering the partial view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430976/rendering-partial-views-using-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options, choosing which one, really depends on how you want the "Browse" functionality to be reused.

Firstly, passing the "Browse" collection model from your `Index` model (probably the more preferable option)

```
@Html.Partial("Browse", model.BrowsePartialModel)
```

Second option, using a `ChildAction`

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Browse()
{
    // instatiate BrowseViewModel with appropriate route values etc
    var model = new BrowseViewModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

Then from your `Index` view

```
@Html.Action("Browse")
```

Comment: think i'll stick with the first option, viewmodels are my next goal once i understand basic stuff. thanks