# Rendering Partial Views using AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a very simple task, I have to render Partial Views on the main Page so that the whole Page is not loaded every time I click a link rather just that particular `div` or `section`.

Check this out:

- [Link](http://demo.webhr.co/hr/home/#).

When you click a link at the header on the above website, it only loads the particular section not the whole page.

I have tried many solutions on the Internet but I could not make it work.

**Solutions I have tried:**

- [Link](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/8e131adf-2621-4cd7-8557-770c1ede799c/Calling%20partial%20view%20using%20Ajax%20in%20ASP%20NET%20MVC%204)
- [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430976/rendering-partial-views-using-ajax)
- [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381533(v=vs.100).aspx)

Since I can not explain all of them, I am only going to ask about this one:

[Link](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/8e131adf-2621-4cd7-8557-770c1ede799c/Calling%20partial%20view%20using%20Ajax%20in%20ASP%20NET%20MVC%204)

After reading a lot of tutorials I got the dummy Project to work but its not working in a Project that my team is working on:

1. I added a PartialView in my `Home` named `Partial`.
2. I added a Method in my `Home` Controller:

   ```
   public PartialViewResult Test()
   {
       return PartialView();
   }
   ```
3. I added a button in my `Index`:

   ```
   <input type="submit" id="clik" />
   ```
4. My JavaScript:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#clik').click(function () {
       $("#s").load("/Home/Test");
       });
   </script>
   ```
5. I added the following references:

   ```
   <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```

**Screen Shot before I click Submit**

[image]

**Screen Shot after I click Submit**

[image]

This is working fine on my dummy Project but not on the Project my team is working on, When I try to implement this following the exact same steps written above I am getting the following errors while inspecting the Page through `Google Chrome Developer Tools`:

```
GET http://localhost/Employees/Test 404 (Not Found) 
    jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
        send                        jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
        f.extend.ajax               jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
        f.fn.extend.load            jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
        (anonymous function)        Employees:278
        f.event.dispatch            jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
        h.handle.i                  jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
```

I am a beginner to ASP .Net MVC and I am using ASP .Net MVC 4...

Comment: The message suggests the `Test` method in `EmployeesController` does no exist. Check by entering that address in the browser address bar

Comment: @StephenMuecke I put the address in the browser and the `Test` method is working fine... Can you think of another problem that might be returning this message?

Comment: Not sure, but you do have another problem. Your button is `type="submit"` which is going to submit the form. It should be `type="button" or modify your script to `$('#clik').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ....` to stop the form submitting. Note also you refer to both HomeController and EmployeeController (as per the error message)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tried @Venkat's approach and it worked, however I still did not get the above way to work... it did not work even after I modified it to `button` and I am only refering to `EmployeesController`. Here:
`$("#change").load("/Employees/Test");`

Comment: Your question had `$("#s").load("/Home/Test");` so I assume that was just a typo. If it works using an ajax action link then it should work using `.load()` so not sure where the problem is but it definitely cant find `//localhost/Employees/Test` if the error is 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things simpler:

1. Create an ajax action link for each of the menu link.
2. Set the `UpdateTargetId` as the `id` of `div` where you want to show your partial view.

Comment: I had tried this before so many times and it was not working, after reading your answer I tried this and it worked, :)

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi Glad to hear you saying 'worked'. Have a nice day.