# Why I can not call method from another one in the same controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I try to call method that returns `View` inside of another method, but in the same controller. There is my code:

```
public ActionResult GetAnswer(List<PossibleAnswerVM> possibleAnswers)
{
    if (IsLastQuestion(possibleAnswers.FirstOrDefault().IdQuestion))
    {
        return Index();
    }
    return null;
}
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Anketa> anketas = Manager.SelectAnketa();
    return View(anketas);
}
```

And there is the form which call `GetAnswer()`

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetAnswer", "Survey", FormMethod.Post,
    new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Ответить" 
        onclick="answerClick(@Model.FirstOrDefault().OrdQuestion);" 
        class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Also I have tried `RedirectToAction()` and call methods from another controller.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: `public static bool`...

Comment: When you say you cannot call that method what exactly do you mean?  Are you getting a compilation error, a runtime exception?  If so please post the message you are getting.

Comment: Actually the problem is that nothing happens. Process goes to breakpoint at the `return Index();` statement, and then goes inside the `Index()` method but appropriate `View` does not appear.

Comment: @VitalyIsaenko can you post the code in your Index() method

Comment: @David alredy posted. Edited the post by addind code of the method.

Comment: But you're calling your action with ajax.

Comment: @VitalyIsaenko Ive editted my answer just don't call the index, return the view straight from the GetAnswer()

Comment: @VitalyIsaenko see below answer edited again return View("VIEWNAME", anketas);

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria I supposed that it can affect. And tried to change to `@Html.BeginForm()`. Unfortunately it didn't help either.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria I'm really sorry, you were right. I changed another view. Can you please to help me understand why doesn't it work with ajax call? And how to do it using ajax?

Comment: Take a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430976/rendering-partial-views-using-ajax).

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria Thank you, I tried offered code, but it didn't help me. I suppose that in accepted answer code does the same thing as `Ajax.BeginForm()` does. Am I right? Nevertheless, I couldn't solve the problem this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
public ActionResult GetAnswer(List<PossibleAnswerVM> possibleAnswers)
{
    if (IsLastQuestion(possibleAnswers.FirstOrDefault().IdQuestion))
    {
          IEnumerable<Anketa> anketas = Manager.SelectAnketa();
          return View("VIEWNAME", anketas);
    }
    return null;
}

private static bool IsLastQuestion(int idQuestion)
{
    var returnValue = false;

    Question question = Manager.GetQuestion(idQuestion);
    List<Question> questions = Manager.SelectQuestions(question.idAnketa);

    if (questions.Count == Manager.GetCountQuestionsAnswered(question.idAnketa, SessionUser.PersonID))
    {
        returnValue = true;
    }                      
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: I tried to return `View()` instead of `Action()`, but it didn't help too. In addition, I need to initialise object for strongly-typed view.

Comment: @VitalyIsaenko can you post the code in your Index() method, ive changed above to return the index() - nice to see whats in there.

Comment: yes, this approach helped, thank you. But why can't I return method instead of view?