# Why isn't my page doing a refresh when calling my controller though an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Here is my markup that executes the JavaScript/ajax callback to the controller. What I am trying to do is have this click function activate a tab component, which it does, and execute the action in the Controller.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" onclick="setCert(0);" data-toggle="tab">Registered</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" onclick="setCert(1);" data-toggle="tab">Certified</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the JavaScript

```
   function setCert(cert){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/CommunitiesLanding/' + cert,
            type: "GET",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: "application/json",

            success: function () {

                console.log('success!!');
            }
        });
```

and lastly here is my controller:

```
 public ActionResult CommunitiesLanding(int id)
    {
        var model = new CommunitiesViewModel();
        var comm = new List<CommunityPoints>();
        var mapPoints = new List<CommunityPoints>();
        var mapPoints2 = new List<CommunityPoints>();
        var regComm = new List<Registered>();
        var certComm = new List<Certified>();
        var locationService = new GoogleLocationService();
        var communites = db.Communities.Where(x => x.Certified != true).OrderBy(x => x.CommunityState).ToList();
        var certCommunities = db.Communities.Where(x => x.Certified == true).OrderBy(x => x.CommunityState).ToList();
        var statecd = communites[0];
        var statecd2 = statecd.CommunityState;

        if (id == 0)
        {

            // Collect the Registered communites data
            foreach (var c in communites)
            {
                if (statecd2 != c.CommunityState)
                {
                    var reg = new Registered();
                    reg.state = statecd2;
                    reg.points = comm;
                    regComm.Add(reg);
                    comm = new List<CommunityPoints>();
                    statecd2 = c.CommunityState;
                }

                var communityPts = new CommunityPoints();
                var points = locationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(c.CommunityZip);
                communityPts.CommunityId = c.CommunityId;
                communityPts.CommunityName = c.ComunityName;
                communityPts.latitude = points.Latitude.ToString();
                communityPts.longitude = points.Longitude.ToString();
                communityPts.state = c.CommunityState;
                comm.Add(communityPts);
                mapPoints.Add(communityPts);

            }

            // Collect the very last collection of state data
            var Lastreg = new Registered();
            Lastreg.state = statecd2;
            Lastreg.points = comm;
            comm = new List<CommunityPoints>();
            regComm.Add(Lastreg);

        }
        else
        {
            // Collect Data For the Certified Communites
            statecd = certCommunities[0];
            statecd2 = statecd.CommunityState;
            foreach (var c in certCommunities)
            {
                if (statecd2 != c.CommunityState)
                {
                    var cert = new Certified();
                    cert.state = statecd2;
                    cert.points = comm;
                    certComm.Add(cert);
                    comm = new List<CommunityPoints>();
                    statecd2 = c.CommunityState;
                }

                var communityPts = new CommunityPoints();
                var points = locationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(c.CommunityZip);
                communityPts.CommunityId = c.CommunityId;
                communityPts.CommunityName = c.ComunityName;
                communityPts.latitude = points.Latitude.ToString();
                communityPts.longitude = points.Longitude.ToString();
                communityPts.state = c.CommunityState;
                comm.Add(communityPts);
                mapPoints2.Add(communityPts);
            }

            // Collect the very last collection of state data
            var Lastcert = new Certified();
            Lastcert.state = statecd2;
            Lastcert.points = comm;
            comm = new List<CommunityPoints>();
            certComm.Add(Lastcert);
        }

        model.regCommunities = regComm;
        model.cerCommunities = certComm;
        model.regPoints = mapPoints;
        model.certPoints = mapPoints2;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: What MVC framework are you using ?

Comment: Why are you expecting a page refresh? You are making an AJAX call (which does not involve the browser navigating the user anywhere) and are only performing a `console.log` when it succeeds.

Comment: this is using the .NET framework

Comment: I realize that I am making Ajax call, and perhaps you can steer me in the right direction. I want to refresh the page by executing the controller again.

Comment: Do you mean "navigate" to that URL/Route?  Why do the ajax in that case, please clarify

Comment: the navigation part is working ... but I want to refresh the page with new data. I may not explaining this very well

Comment: If you want to dynamically load tab content from controller, consider using partial view. To get the idea have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7431105/551322).

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to make the AJAX request to initialize some data and then redirect the user to the newly initialized page once the server is done processing, you can update your AJAX function to redirect on success:

```
function setCert(cert) {
    var url = '/Home/CommunitiesLanding/' + cert;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function () {
           // redirect user to URL
           location.href = url;
        }
    });
}
```

It might make more sense to just redirect the user directly though, if you don't need to initialize data and wait for it to complete beforehand:

```
function setCert(cert) {
   location.href = '/Home/CommunitiesLanding/' + cert;
}
```

Comment: I wondered these same points also if the attempt is to do some sort of SPA on  some portion of the page with the results...

Comment: that is did not work I am afraid. It did not fire off the controller