# Cascading population of a mvc dropdown

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 DropDowns in an MVC application. Trying to populate the second one based on the first one's chosen value (Cascading).. 
Since I am rather new to MVC this is giving me a little problem.. 
This is how ot looks in my View..

[image: This is the part of my View]

I am getting the data based on the selection in the first DropDown

[image]

This is the JS code for retriving the data..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('#AllShips').change(function () {
            var selectedShip = $("#AllShips").val();
            console.log(selectedShip);
            var arrivalSelect = $('#AllShipArrivals');
            arrivalSelect.empty();
            if (selectedShip != null && selectedShip != '') {
                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetArrivals")', { ShipID: selectedShip }, function (arrivals) {
                    console.log(arrivals);
                    if (arrivals != null && !jQuery.isEmptyObject(arrivals))
                    {
                        arrivalSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                            value: null,
                            text: ""
                        }));
                        $.each(arrivals, function (index, arrival) {
                            console.log(arrival.Value);
                            console.log(arrival.Text);
                            arrivalSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                                value: arrival.Value,
                                text: arrival.Text
                            }));
                        });
                    };
                });
            }
        });
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AllShips, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                @if (Model.AllShips != null)
                                {
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ShipID, Model.AllShips, new { @class = "form-control", id = "AllShips" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ShipID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AllShipArrivals, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                @if (Model.AllShipArrivals != null)
                                {
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ArrivalId, Model.AllShipArrivals, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArrivalId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                }
                                else
                                { @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ArrivalId, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArrivalId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })}
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Still the second DropDown is not changing (initially I populate it with a list of all Arrivals, yes I know..not a good option)

Any idea what I am doing wrong here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the `HTML`, it is what I suspected. In your `JS` your are referencing 2nd DDL by `var arrivalSelect = $('#AllShipArrivals');` but there is no such element (it is, but this is just a label), instead you should use:

```
var arrivalSelect = $('#ArrivalId');
```

Comment: This worked like a charm :) 

It populates the second ddl but it looks wmpty in stead of making the first item selected, any idea on that??

Comment: you have this code `arrivalSelect.append($('<option/>', {value: null,text: ""}));` that inserts empty value at the beginning. Remove it if you don't want to.

Comment: Working lika a charm :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make 'PartialView' or 'ViewComponent' for the second Dropdown, do ajax call on changing selection in the first dropdown, choose data depending on the value you passed during the ajax call, pass the data into your partial view and return it.
Something like

```
public IActionResult SecondDropdownPartial(int selectedShip)
{
    var data = GetSomeData(selectedShip);
    return Partial("ViewName", data);
}
```

In js 'success' you get your view in response. Replace it on the page with

```
$('#container').html(response);
```

for example.
More information : [Rendering Partial Views using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430976/rendering-partial-views-using-ajax)

Answer (score -1):

edited
try making the value to be empty string rather than null

`emptyStr="";`

`arrivalSelect.append('<option value="${emptyStr}"> ${emptyStr} </option>');`
`arrivalSelect.append('<option value="${arrival.Value}"> ${arrival.Text} </option>');`

Comment: try this```arrivalSelect.append('<option value="${arrival.Value}"> ${arrival.Text} </option>');```

Comment: Sorry, no luck :/ Stilll getting data and everythink but the second DDL not changing. One question, I have not inserted my @Html.BeginForm in the view ...is this needed??

Comment: no, could you show html element structure of 2nd dropdown once 1st dropdown is selected

Comment: you can check this from developer controls in the browser