# ASP.NET MVC3 ajax partial view refresh

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I am facing a problem with ajax updating of div in asp.net mvc3.

I have a View with content

```
<div id="post_comments">
   @{Html.RenderPartial("_RefreshComments", Model);}
 </div>
<div id="commentForm">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Details", new { id = Model.Post.PostId }, new AjaxOptions
           {
              HttpMethod = "POST",
              InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, 
              UpdateTargetId = "post_comments"
            }
          ))
{
// form content goes here
<p id="buttons">
    <input type="submit" value="@Strings.Save" />
</p>
}
```

This is my partial view

```
@model Project.Models.Posts.PostDetailsViewModel   

@{ 
    foreach (var c in Model.ApprovedComments)
    { 
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => c)        
    } 
}
```

I have a controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int id, FormCollection form )
{
    var model = new PostDetailsViewModel(UnitOfWork, id);
    return PartialView("_RefreshComments", model);

}
```

I have following script included in my layout cshtml

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and also

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

It really works, I am able to add comments, but controller only returns the PartialView, not contained in the layout. I am found [ASP.net MVC3 - Razor Views and PartialViews with Ajax Postbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888521/asp-net-mvc3-razor-views-and-partialviews-with-ajax-postbacks) but nothing from there helped me.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you see the AJAX request being triggered in your javascript debugging tool in the browser? Could there be some javascript errors? Did you ensure that the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` script exists at the specified location. Did you reference `jquery` as well?

Comment: Nope, Request.IsAjaxRequest() always returns false. Yes I am sure that script is enabled on all the pages. Yes jquery works but I do not know why it returns false. I have read through some topics about this...but....

Answer (score 2):

I would use jquery ajax to call the action and then return the partial view from the controller. Then reload the returned html into the container using jquery.

First, add a refresh button or something you can trigger the ajax event... then do the below javascript.

Do something like this:

```
<div id="post_comments">     
  @{Html.RenderPartial("_RefreshComments", Model);}    
</div>
<div id="commentForm">
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Details", new { id = Model.Post.PostId }, new AjaxOptions    
  {
     HttpMethod = "POST",
     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, 
     UpdateTargetId = "post_comments"
  }
))
{
// form content goes here
<p id="buttons">
  <input type="submit" value="@Strings.Save" />
  <input type="button" id="refreshButton" value="Refresh" />"
</p>
}





$('#refreshButton').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: 'controller/Details.aspx',
      datatype: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
         $('#post_comments').empty().html(data);
      }
   }); 
});
```

Obviously, the url needs to be the route to your action. Other than that, this should work fine for you.

Comment: It almost works, but I am facing some problems with passing params through the @Url.Action(). I need to pass formcollection and Id.

Answer (score 0):

Usage:

```
    function onUploadComplete()
    {
        @Ajax.Update("targetId", helper => helper.Action("ActionName"))
    }
```

And the code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// I'd rather stab myself in the eye with a fork than bothering with php ever again and living without extension methods
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="helper">makes sense to make it available here. who likes dozens of new helper classes</param>
    /// <param name="updateTargetId">simple enough</param>
    /// <param name="actionUrlFactory">resharper will show if we're messing stuff up. hurray.</param>
    /// <param name="isAsync">speaks for itself</param>
    /// <param name="options">might as well reuse that one for callbacks</param>
    /// <returns>generated code with compile time checks</returns>
    public static IHtmlString Update(this AjaxHelper helper, string updateTargetId, Func<UrlHelper, string> actionUrlFactory, bool isAsync = true, AjaxOptions options = null)
    {
        var requestUrl = actionUrlFactory(new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext));
        if (options == null)
        {
            options = new AjaxOptions()
            {
                AllowCache = false,
                HttpMethod = "GET"
            };
        }

        string cache = options.AllowCache ? "true" : "false";
        string success = options.OnSuccess.Length > 0 ? ".done(" + options.OnSuccess + ")" : "";
        string fail = options.OnFailure.Length > 0 ? ".fail(" + options.OnFailure + ")" : "";
        string always = options.OnComplete.Length > 0 ? ".always(" + options.OnComplete + ")" : "";
        string isAsyncString = isAsync ? "true" : "false";

        // of course you can go way further here, but this is good enough for me. just sharing since i didn't find a nice solution here that doesnt involve writing js manually every time.
        string js = string.Format(@"
            $.ajax({{
                cache : {7},
                async : {6},
                url : '{0}',
                type : '{1}'
            }})
            .done(function(data){{
                $('#{5}').html(data);
            }});
            {2}
            {3}
            {4}
        ", requestUrl, options.HttpMethod, success, fail, always, updateTargetId, isAsyncString, cache);

        return new HtmlString(js);
    }
```