# Refreshing parts of a web page using browser console

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, browser

I get tired of waiting when the whole page refreshes even though I have made changes to the partial views. =)

Is there a way where I can only reload those partial views (through the browser console) and not the whole page? :D

[image]

Its stupid but worth a shot!

P.S. I admit I am a lazy developer :P

Comment: I think you are looking for AJAX

Comment: Can I reload the partial using ajax in browser console??

Comment: yes, just google for "AJAX refresh partial views"... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564556/asp-net-mvc3-ajax-partial-view-refresh

Comment: No.! I want to refresh it using browser console. I mean developer tools that are supported by Web Browser such as in Chrome

Comment: Why is it taking so long for your website to load? Maybe look into that first.

Comment: You cant load just a part of a website if this website isn't made for this, means that what you want to do isn't possible...

Comment: @putvande I think he doesn't want to reload his website, I think he wants to reload any website ;-)

Comment: I guess it is possible if you know the structure of server-side (For example: you know that "/url/site/xxx", reutrn the comments, so you ask for it to the server and then update it ), but it is a pain....why would you want to do this?

Comment: The website takes time to load. And when I make changes to a partial view then I have to reload the whole page. :(

Also I have tried everything to make the page as fast as possible. :|

Comment: Any browser-specific extensions/plugin would also be great.! Or any extension in visual studio!?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see your changes immediately reflected to the webpage, then [LiveReload](http://livereload.com) can help.

Comment: Yes.. Something like this.! Can you suggest some alternatives?

Comment: See this http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86189-i-don-t-like-livereload-can-you-recommend-somethi

Comment: For me Livereload works best. Also, if you like the answer, mark it :)

Comment: Unfortunately, It is not working in Google Chrome. :(

Comment: Have you tried extension method or manual js addition method? Former works for me

Comment: I have tried the extension for Chrome and Firefox. It does not work. It says "Could not connect to LiveReload servers."

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Example:

```
<p id="yourContent">old content</p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'url_to_your_new_content.php'
    }).done(function( data ) {
       $('#yourContent').text(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No. I am not looking for an ajax call.!